# 'Backend icinga is not running' error in icinga web interface

Tags: icinga2

Under System > Monitoring Health, I'm getting a "Backend icinga is not running" error which details the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Uncaught ErrorException: setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, float given in /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Response.php:326 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Icinga\Application\ApplicationBootstrap->Icinga\Application{closure}(2, 'setcookie() exp...', '/usr/share/php/...', 326, Array) #1 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Response.php(326): setcookie('icingaweb2-appl...', '{"acknowledged-...', 2147483648, '/icingaweb2/', NULL, true, true) #2 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Response.php(338): Icinga\Web\Response->sendCookies() #3 /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(762): Icinga\Web\Response->sendHeaders() #4 /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Controller/Front.php(975): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendResponse() #5 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/Web.php(300): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(Object(Icinga\Web\Request), Object(Icinga\Web\Response)) #6 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/webrouter.php(104): Icinga\Application\Web->dispatch() in /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 259

It seems to me like an Icinga web code exception, but maybe it's on my side. Has anyone seen this before? I'm using a raspbian.

Comment: Have you looked at the backend? Icinga is typically self-hosted, so if you're the one hosting it you're the one who will have access to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I did look into my server's configurations. I'm self-hosting the application and I followed through the official setup guide without customizations. I'm puzzled because I can't find this error documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For me, digging into the error showed an error on following command:

`icinga2 daemon -C`

Following shows ownership error

`ls -la /etc/icinga2/features-available/`

Fix:

`chown icinga:icinga /etc/icinga2/features-available/ido-mysql.conf 
icinga2 daemon -C
systemctl reload rh-php71-php-fpm.service
systemctl reload icinga2`